# Script to update maven dependencies in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

can anyone provide a script that can update maven dependencies automatically by reading the correct version from remote repository because its very tedious job to update maven dependency by looking into different projects

Comment: If you need maven to pick the latest version (Be it release or snapshot) then you can use `<version>LATEST</version>`. If just Latest Released versions then you can use `<version>RELEASE</version>`.

Comment: Don't use `RELEASE` and `LATEST` cause it is marked deprecated. `-U` is only for SNAPSHOT's not for dependencies...

Comment: Take a look at [versions-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/)

Answer (score 0):

```
mvn clean install -U
```

-U means force update of dependencies.
This will load the latest version of the dependencies from the repository assuming the dependencies defined in `pom.xml` does not declare the version explicitly.

Comment: simply wrong, cause `-U` is for SNAPSHOT's only..no relationship to dependencies.

Comment: the question doesnot say wether it is for SNAPSHOTs. Anyway without -U will also check for new versions of dependencies.

Comment: Hm..you say Maven will check for new versions of dependencies if i use `mvn clean install`? How will that work?